# delete last line from text file vba

Tags: vba, text

I am saving data from spreadsheet into text file and every time I open it, there is blank line after the last data which I need it to be at the last value. So I need to re-open the text file and hit the backspace from text file and then re-save it. I am looking for vba to do this automatically when saving it.

Now I have done some research and tested them but none of them works. Meaning they don't remove the blank line. When I execute my current codes, the saving part works but not the line removing part. Nothing happens, no error and it doesn't remove the blank line. I have included pictures of what I need vba to do, note where the cursor needs to be.  I am hoping to achieve saving and removing the blank line in 1 module as well.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
Dim strTemplateFile As String
Dim strFname As String
Dim strFnameClean As String
Dim FileSaveName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Save file name and path into a variable
strTemplateFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

' Default directory would be c:\temp.  Users however will have the ability
' to change where to save the file if need be.

FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
               InitialFileName:="C:\Users\SC1324\Desktop\test.txt", _
               fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If FileSaveName = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' Save file as .txt TAB delimited fileSaveName, FileFormat:=36,
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                      FileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, _
                      CreateBackup:=False

strFname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strFnameClean = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".txt", "clean.txt")
Call Test(strFname, strFnameClean)
End Sub


Sub Test(ByVal strFname, ByVal strFnameClean)
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTF As Object
Dim strAll As String
Dim varTxt
Dim lngRow As Long
iNumberOfLinesToDelete = 1


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFname, ForReading)
strAll = objTF.ReadAll
objTF.Close
Set objTF = objFSO.createTextFile(strFnameClean, ForWriting)
objTF.write Mid(strAll, 1, Len(strAll) - 2)
objTF.Close
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
Dim strTemplateFile As String
Dim strFname As String
Dim strFnameClean As String
Dim FileSaveName

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Save file name and path into a variable
strTemplateFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

' Default directory would be c:\temp.  Users however will have the ability
' to change where to save the file if need be.

FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
               InitialFileName:="C:\Users\sc1324\Desktop\test.txt", _
               fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If FileSaveName = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

' Save file as .txt TAB delimited fileSaveName, FileFormat:=36,
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                      FileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, _
                      CreateBackup:=False

strFname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strFnameClean = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".txt", "clean.txt")
Call Test(strFname, strFnameClean)
End Sub


Sub Test(ByVal strFname, ByVal strFnameClean)
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTF As Object
Dim strAll As String
Dim varTxt
Dim lngRow As Long
iNumberOfLinesToDelete = 1


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFname, ForReading)
strAll = objTF.ReadAll
objTF.Close
Set objTF = objFSO.createTextFile(strFnameClean, ForWriting)
objTF.write Mid(strAll, 1, Len(strAll) - 2)
objTF.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Really not sure why you write each line at a time...

```
Const FOR_READING = 1
Const FOR_WRITING = 2
strFileName = "C:\Users\sc1324\Desktop\test.txt"
iNumberOfLinesToDelete = 1

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_READING)
strContents = objTS.ReadAll
objTS.Close

Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING)
objTS.write mid(strContents,1,len(strContents)-2)
objTS.Close
```

Should suffice?

Also note the documentation for [WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writeline-method)...

> Writes a specified string **and newline character** to a TextStream file

So you will want to use `write()`

---

Edit:

If I were you I'd do the following:

```
sub backupSheet(sht as worksheet, ByVal path as string)
   Dim v as variant
   v=sht.UsedRange.Value.
   Dim i,j as integer, s as string
   For i = lbound(v,1) to ubound(v,1)
      For j = lbound(v,2) to ubound(v,2)
         s = s & v(i,j) & ","
      Next j
      s = mid(s,1,len(s)-1) & vbCrLf
   Next i
   s = mid(s,1,len(s)-2)
   Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(path, 2)
   objTS.write(s)
   objTS.close
end sub
sub test()
   Dim ws as worksheet
   for each ws in ThisWorkbook.sheets
      backupSheet ws, ThisWorkbook.path & "\test_" & ws.name & ".csv"
   next
end sub
```

Or something similar

Comment: Thanks but when I open the file, the blank line is still there. And any chance you can incorporate the saving and deleting the blank line into 1 module? I got the second part of codes based on research and haven't being able to get it to work.

Comment: All this does is write out the same content. It doesn't delete the lines as the question asks, and it doesn't remove the blank line at the end.

Comment: @sc1324 apologies, I was more worried that you were using `WriteLine` v.s. `Write` It's probably why it didn't work when you were trying it. I've changed the code snippet though. It should trim the vbCrLf from the end of the file.

Comment: @sc1324 I've added a part on the end which should have a full working procedure for backing up the sheet. It should suffice for what you need + be optimal :) But currently I have untested it as I'm not on my PC

Comment: I tried your revised codes but I am getting Permission Denied at line `Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName, FOR_WRITING)`

Comment: I was able to find something online and incorporate what I need. Look for my answer if anyone needs help.

Comment: @sc1324 you should accept your own answer as a solution when you can :)